# PHP Redirect - IF with multiple conditions

Tags: php

I'm having an issue with something quite simple and I have no idea why.

Need a fresh pair of eyes.

In my configuration file I am pulling a users profile information, if their profile is incomplete and they are not in the: home, settings, logout, profile error page then they will be redirected.

Basically I am making it mandatory or they won't be able to navigate to other areas of the system.

```
$link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
if($counter<9 && ($link !="home" OR $link !="logout" OR $link !="profileError" OR $link !="profileSettings")){
    header('Location: profileError');
    kill();
}
```

I've tested my counter which seems to be working fine.

Any help would be appreiated!

Comment: So what's the issue?  Where is `$counter` set?  Use an else and print out debug info like counter and link.

Answer (score 0):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` contains the full pathname of the file from the URL, e.g. `/home.php` or `/folder/logout.php`. So none of your `$link` tests will work. Try:

```
$link = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php');
```

to get just the filename without the `.php` extension.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try to `debug` your code first `echo $link` and `$counter` both or add `else` to see whats wrong

```
    $link = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    //echo $link; echo $counter;

    if($counter<9 && ($link !="home" OR $link !="logout" OR $link !="profileError" OR $link !="profileSettings")){
        header('Location: profileError');
        kill();
    }
else{

echo "there is some error"."</br>";
echo $link; echo $counter;
}
```

Comment: Hi the counter is coming back as 0 (as I have not completed any profile fields), the changed code:
$link = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php');
has been added which is giving me "profileError" on echo which means the variables are correct.

The if statement is not picking these up. It is telling me there are too many redirects when I am on the "profileError" page but, with the IF statement I have made it so it shouldn't redirect if on this page...

Answer (score 0):

Comment your condition and test the header location, if the header location does not work, check your condition if don't have something error.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to get it working.

```
$link = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php');
if($counter <9){
if($link !="home" OR $link !="logout" OR $link !="profileError" OR $link !="profileSettings"){
    header('Location: profileError');
    kill();
}
}
```

Not sure why splitting the IF statements helped but at least it works.

Answer (score 0):

You should have used `&&` condition operator instead of `||` (OR).

Translated : If the page is not called X and Y then ... Otherwise, If the page is not called X or Y then... it would always be called.

```
$link = basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '.php');
if($counter <9){
    if($link !="home" && $link !="logout" && $link !="profileError" && $link !="profileSettings"){
        header('Location: profileError');
        kill();
    }
}
```